# Flattening the output of Solve[]

Tags: equation-solving, programming

I want to flatten the output of solve into a an un-nested list.
For instance,

```
Solve[y[x] == x^2 + c, c]
```

yields

```
{{c -> -x^2 + y[x]}}
```

which I may reduce using Flatten[] to

```
eq=Flatten[%]
{c -> -x^2 + y[x]}
```

However, this is still not a list.

If I call List@@ on it, I get

```
List @@ Flatten[eq]
{c -> -x^2 + y[x]}
```

So the solution is not fully flattened.

Currently, I have to do

```
List @@ Flatten[eq][[1]]
{c, -x^2 + y[x]}
```

Ultimately I would like to be able to directly take answers from Solve and use functions like List @@ and Equals @@ on them to reassign the -> operator, rather than the programmatic way I currently do it which is using list references.

Is there a more elegant way to swap the [rule] operator for the Equal == or other operators?

edit:

**From the comments -**

Apply[#,1] or @@@ works, but is somewhat kludgy, as it does not fully flatten the list. For instance:

```
List @@@ Flatten[eq]
{{c, -x^2 + y[x]}}
```

**My expected result** 
either a list of depth 1 - in the case of flattening into one list, eg

```
{c, -x^2 + y[x]}
```

or in the case of using Equal or another assignment

```
c == -x + y[x]
```

Comment: Like `Equal @@@ Flatten[{{c -> -x^2 + y[x]}}]`?

Comment: I see, so it is just a matter of using the @@@ to go into the second level? Thank you

Comment: It is `Apply[#, {1}]` so almost the second :)

Comment: If I use this method with List @@@ Flatten[{{c -> -x^2 + y[x]}}], I will still yield a nested list, which I have to use flatten on again.

Comment: Isn't my first comment giving you the final solution?

Comment: Yes, it is close, but the result is still buried in a list.  I don't know if that will actually affect my usage.  In order to reach into the list, I use a list slice, which seems redundant -  I would like to avoid using ugly list slices

Comment: The output is {c == -x^2 + y[x]}, or illustratively - List @@@ Flatten[{{c -> -x^2 + y[x]}}] yields {{c, -x^2 + y[x]}}

Comment: Use `First` but what if there are two solutions? and please include an exact expected result in the question.,

Comment: I see the shortcomings of what I am looking for.  I edited my question to include an exact expected result

Comment: General approach: `Or @@ And @@@ Solve[y[x] == x^2 + c^2 && b^2 == c, {b, c}] /. Rule -> Equal`.  Your `List` answer relies on the equation having exactly one solution; a general approach substituting `Rule -> List` can't work on it, but a specialized one could, such as `Flatten[eq /. Rule -> List]`.